# sagepay recurring payments in nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce, opayo

Has anyone worked on sagepay recurring payments in nopcommerce before?
I need to work on that and every help/advice will be more then welcome.

Answer (score 0):

there is as of now 2 free open source modules for that purpose.

1. http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/559/sagepay-server-payment-module-uk.aspx
2. http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1211/sagepay-server-payment-plugin-iframe-redirect-modes.aspx

and 3 paid versions.

1. http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1148/sagepay-direct-payment-plugin.aspx
2. http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1894/sagepay-form.aspx
3. http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1403/sage-payment-solutions-integration-plugin.aspx

i am sure you can contact either one of them for guidance, if its still relevant.